# How can a snapshot be obtained from a MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, media-player, surfaceview

An Android app has a MediaPlayer with a SurfaceView holder. The MediaPlayer streams video flawlessly. The following code is used to get a snapshot:

```
vSurfaceHostingMediaPlayer.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bimap bm = vSurfaceHostingMediaPlayer.getDrawingCache(false);
```

where vSurfaceHostingMediaPlayer is the SurfaceView hosting the MediaPlayer.  The obtained bitmap has the right dimensions (i.e. width and height), but is always uniformly black.

When the same above code is applied to an ImageView in the same app, it works perfectly.

What is the right way to get a snapshot of the video played in a MediaPlayer?

Comment: I suspect that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
View v = view.getRootView();
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be even worse because the bitmap is null with this code.